# Python tkinter hangs when I try to close graphs

Tags: python, tkinter

I've tried using Tk to make a function that will allow users to look at a graph and select if points are wrong. I had this working before, but now my code is hanging every time I run it and try to go to the next graph. Specifically when I click "next graph" and it should run

```
def _quit(self):
   self.master.destroy()  # stops mainloop
```

When I manually stop the code I get this message:

```
  File "C:\Users\laura\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1429, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)

KeyboardInterrupt
```

Any suggestions? I've read using root.destroy() but I haven't been able to get that to work

Thanks!

```
    def config_plot():
    tk, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set(title='Are the peaks okay?')
    return (tk, ax)


class matplotlibSwitchGraphs:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(12,7))
        self.ax = self.fig.gca()
        
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.master)  
        self.config_window()
        
        self.graphIndex = 0
        self.draw_graph_one()
        

    def config_window(self):
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self.master)
        toolbar.update()
        
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        
        print('connect')
        self.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.on_button_press)

        self.button = Button(self.master, text="YES, next graph", command=self._quit) #this is where it gets stuck!
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.button_switch = Button(self.master, text="NO", command=self.switch_graphs)
        self.button_switch.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def draw_graph_one(self):
        self.ax.clear() # clear current axes
        self.ax.plot(data)
        self.ax.plot(peaks,loc_peaks, marker='o', linestyle='none')
        # self.ax.set(xlim=(touchdown_cut[-15]-50,toeoff_cut[-5]+50))
        self.ax.set(title='Check the data')
        self.canvas.draw()

    def draw_graph_two(self):
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(data)
        self.ax.set(title='Click all the incorrect peaks')
        self.ax.plot(peaks,loc_peaks, marker='o', linestyle='none')
        self.canvas.draw()
        

    def on_button_press(self, event):
        print('xdata, ydata:', event.xdata, event.ydata)
        # return (event.xdata)
        
        
        global ix
        ix = event.xdata
        
        global clicks
        clicks.append((ix))

        array1 = np.asarray(peaks)
        idx1 = (np.abs(array1 - event.xdata)).argmin()
        
        
        global peaks_adj
        global loc_peaks_adj

        peaks_adj = np.delete(peaks, idx1)
        loc_peaks_adj = np.delete(loc_peaks, idx1)

        
        self.canvas.flush_events()
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(data)
        self.ax.set(title='Click all the incorrect peaks')
        self.ax.plot(peaks_adj,loc_peaks_adj, marker='o', linestyle='none')
        self.canvas.draw()
        return (clicks)
        
    
    def _quit(self):
        self.master.destroy()  # stops mainloop

    def switch_graphs(self):
        # Need to call the correct draw, whether we're on graph one or two
        self.graphIndex = (self.graphIndex + 1 ) % 2
        if self.graphIndex == 0:
            self.draw_graph_one()
        else:
            self.draw_graph_two()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    matplotlibSwitchGraphs(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The code works fine in my Windows 10 with Python 3.10.3 after adding missing variables, like `data`, `peak`, `loc_peak` and `clicks`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `root.destroy()` to self.destroy()`as you are working with classes. If using function through a button remove the`()`after command like`command=self.destroy`.

Also don't use `global`, use `self.` to create a class variable if you want to access the variable in multiple function.

As far as for lags, I would recommend you to use `update` and `update_idletasks`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently using a button with a command that sends it to -> self.master.destroy(), and it seems Tk is still running indefinitely. When I hit the button the window closes, but it doesn't seem like Tk stops running

Comment: @Lheal , Can you describe how tkinter doesnt seem to be stopped?

Comment: I got it to work with self.master.quit()!
With destroy() it wouldn't continue to my next code, and I would have to manually hit stop